# Bootstrap issue on chrome, fine on Edge

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I seem to have an issue with boostrap on Chrome. It seems to work fine on Edge. The issue is that there should be 3 divs but only the last 2 show up on Chrome?

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="item active">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-xs-6 col-sm-4">
      <div class="member">
        <p>
          <img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail img-circle" src="images/skull.png" alt="">
        </p>
        <h3>InsideJobOCN
          <small class="designation">Commander<br />(North America)</small>
        </h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-xs-6 col-sm-4">
      <div class="member">
        <p>
          <img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail img-circle" src="images/conq.png" alt="">
        </p>
        <h3>InsideJobOCN
          <small class="designation">Commander<br />(North America)</small>
        </h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-xs-6 col-sm-4">
      <div class="member">
        <p>
          <img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail img-circle" src="images/conq.png" alt="">
        </p>
        <h3>SirConqueror
          <small class="designation">Website Creator<br />Executive Officer</small>
        </h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: OSX Chrome Version 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit) displaying 3 divs, 2 columns at xs, 3 columns at sm, as expected

Comment: I am also using the same version in 32-bit (Windows 7 OS) and working as expected.